# ¿Cómo agregar una cookie o localStorage para que deje de aparecer la aceptación ya aceptado?

Tags: jquery

Estuve agregando el siguiente código pero existía error en ejecutar aquí, lo enlace aquí su funcionamiento https://jsfiddle.net/yo953L4k/1/ como puedo hacer para evitar que aparezca cada vez que recargue el sitio el mismo mensaje de aceptación de las políticas y cookies de mi sitio.

Un ejemplo que lo encontré en codepen y, lo adapte pero parce mucho para algo que parecía ser sencillo.

Me pueden explicar que detalle le podría agregar para que una vez este aceptado las políticas este ya deje de aparecer y, de esta manera cumplir con los requerimientos de ley que se exigen.

Este es el código completo js:

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var $cookieAccepteddName    = 'acceptedCookies',
            $cookieDeclinedName     = 'declinedCookies',
            $acceptExpiryDays       = 365,
            $declineExpiryDays      = 1,
            $acceptCookiesOnScroll  = false,
            $scrollOffset           = 120,
      $demo             = true,  
            $cookiesBox             = $('.material-cookies-box'),
            $cookiesModal           = $('.material-cookies-modal'),
            $cookiesModalOverlay    = $('.modal-cookies-overlay'),
            $body                   = $('html,body'),
            $acceptCookiesBtn       = $('#acceptCookies'),
            $moreInfoBtn            = $('#editPreferences'),
            $acceptCookiesBtnModal  = $('#acceptCookiesModal'),
            $declineCookiesBtnModal = $('#declineCookiesModal');


        /**
         * Function that opens the cookies consent box
         * It checks if the user has agreed or declined the cookies
         * If nothing of the above is true the cookies consent is shown
         */
        function showCookiesConsentModal(){

            var $agreed     = getCookie( $cookieAccepteddName ),
                $declined   = getCookie( $cookieDeclinedName );

            if( !$agreed && !$declined ){

                $cookiesBox.addClass('show');

            }

        }


        /**
         * Function that creates a web cookie
         *
         * @param cname string
         * @param cvalue string
         * @param exdays int
         */
        function setCookie( cname, cvalue, exdays) {

      if( !$demo ){
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime( d.getTime() + ( exdays*24*60*60*1000 ) );

        var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
      }

        }


        /**
         * Gets the value of a cookie based on the cookie name
         *
         * @param cname string
         */
        function getCookie( cname ) {

            var name            = cname + "=",
                decodedCookie   = decodeURIComponent( document.cookie ),
                ca              = decodedCookie.split(';');

            for( var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {

                var c = ca[i];

                while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {

                    c = c.substring(1);

                }

                if ( c.indexOf(name) === 0 ) {

                    return c.substring( name.length, c.length );
                }

            }

            return "";

        }


        /**
         * Deletes a cookie based on the cookie name
         *
         * @param name string
         */
        function delete_cookie( name ) {

            document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

        }


        /**
         * Deletes all the cookies
         * It fetches the list of the website cookies
         * foreach cookie the delete_cookie function is called
         *
         */
        function removeAllCookies() {

            var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');

            for ( var i = 1; i <= theCookies.length; i++ ) {

                if (theCookies[i - 1]) {

                    var $cookieName = theCookies[i - 1].split('=')[0];
                    delete_cookie( $cookieName );

                }

            }

            setCookie( $cookieDeclinedName, true, $declineExpiryDays );

        }


        /**
         * Opens the Modal with the More Information
         * It also disables the scroll when the modal is open
         */
        function openCookiesModal(){

            $cookiesModal.addClass('open');
            $cookiesModalOverlay.fadeIn();
            $body.css('overflow', 'hidden');

        }


        /**
         * Closes the Modal with the More Information
         * It also enables the scroll when the modal is closed
         */
        function closeCookiesModal(){

            $cookiesModal.removeClass('open');
            $cookiesModalOverlay.fadeOut();
            $body.css('overflow', '');

        }


        /**
         * This runs when the user accepts the cookies
         * It closes the cookies consent box
         * It also set a cookie that the user has accepted the cookies on website
         */
        function acceptCookiesCallback(){

            $cookiesBox.addClass('hideCookiesContent cookiesAccepted');
            setCookie( $cookieAccepteddName, true, $acceptExpiryDays );

        }


        /**
         * We check if we should show the cookies consent
         */
        showCookiesConsentModal();


        /**
         * Accept Cookies Event Handler
         * Triggers the animation for closing the cookies consent box
         * It also set a cookie that the user has accepted the cookies on website
         */
        $acceptCookiesBtn.on('click', function () {

            acceptCookiesCallback();

        });



        /**
         * More info Event Handler
         * It opens the More Information Modal
         * It also hides the Cookies Consent Box
         */
        $moreInfoBtn.on('click', function () {

            $cookiesBox.addClass('hideCookiesContent cookiesAccepted');
            openCookiesModal();

        });



        /**
         * Accept Cookies Modal Event Handler
         * It closes the More Information Modal
         * It also sets a cookie that the user has accepted the cookies on website
         */
        $acceptCookiesBtnModal.on('click', function () {

            closeCookiesModal();
            setCookie( $cookieAccepteddName, true, $acceptExpiryDays );

        });



        /**
         * Decline Cookies Modal Event Handler
         * It closes the More Information Modal
         * It also sets a cookie that the user has declined the cookies on website
         */
        $declineCookiesBtnModal.on('click', function () {

            closeCookiesModal();
            removeAllCookies();

        });



        /**
         * Accept the cookies if user scrolls on the page
         * This event is running only if $acceptCookiesOnScroll is true
         */
        if( $acceptCookiesOnScroll ) {

            var hasBeenTriggered = false;

            $(window).scroll(function () {

                if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= $scrollOffset && !hasBeenTriggered ) {

                    acceptCookiesCallback();
                    hasBeenTriggered = true;

                }

            });

        }


    }); // Document Ready End

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Quizás te sea mas fácil usar [cookieconsent](https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent/download/) ahí mismo lo puedes configurar, y solo copeas el código y lo pegas en tu sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo aria con localStorage, es tan simple como

```
let accepted_cookies = window.localStorage.getItem('accepted_cookies');

if (!accepted_cookies) {
  document.getElementById('accepted_cookies_form').classList.add('active');
}

const actionBtnAcceptedCookies = () => {
  window.localStorage.setItem('accepted_cookies', 'ok');
  document.getElementById('accepted_cookies_form').classList.remove('active');
}

const actionBtnRejectCookies = () => {
  window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
}
```